# Is the fraction $\frac{x^{y+1}-x}{x-1}$ a natural number?

Tags: number-theory

Is the fraction $\frac{x^{y+1}-x}{x-1}$ a natural number for $x,y$ natural numbers? I mean, is there a $x,y$ solution?

-Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Note that $x-1$ divides $x^y - 1$ for any $x\neq 1$.

Comment: @ZainPatel How can't i see this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of. If $x = 1$, this evaluates to $0/0$, which is not a natural number (or any number, for that matter).

On the other hand,
$$
x^{y+1} - x = x(x-1)\sum_{i=0}^{y-1}x^i
$$
so if $x \ne 1$, then the fraction evaluates to
$$
\frac{x^{y+1} - x}{x - 1} = x\sum_{i=0}^{y-1}x^i
$$
which is clearly a natural number for all $x, y\in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it is. Just write the algorithm division and get the quotient $q(x)$ and the remainder $r$:

$$x^{y+1}-x=(x-1)q(x)+r$$

Placing $x=1$ we get $r=0$ and then $x-1$ divide $x^{y+1}-x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^{y+1}-x}{x-1}=\frac{x(x^{y}-1)}{x-1}= \\
\frac{x(x-1)(x^{y-1}+\cdots+1)}{x-1}$$
Which is always a natural number

Comment: Your factorization is wrong. $x^y -1 = (x-1)\sum_{i=0}^{y-1}x^i$.